# Multi Record Field Definitions smooks CSV header in 1st row

Tags: java, csv, wso2, smooks

I have csv-file like this:

```
123456,01.01.2016,ACME,Johnson
0001,10,100,1000
0002,5,50,250
0003,6,10,60
```

I want to convert it to XML using smooks.
In documentation there is a sample:

```
<csv:reader fields="book[name,author] | magazine[*]" rootElementName="sales" indent="true" />
```

But I do not have name of a record type in a first column.
SOm smomething like this wont work:

```
<csv:reader fields="header[orderNo,orderDate,custId,manager] | line [productId, qty, price, amount]" rootElementName="sales" indent="true" />
```

I need to make smooks understand, that first row has another structure than others. Is it possible?

Comment: What does "smooks" mean?

Comment: Smooks is an extensible framework for building applications for processing XML and non XML

data (CSV, EDI, Java etc) using Java/ Definition from [here](http://www.smooks.org)